# How to display automatically value instead of key in django rest framework for a model attributs which a choice fields?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a DRF api with model attributs with choice field like this:

```
STRONG_FOOT = (
    ("N", "-"),
    ("R", "Right"),
    ("L", "Left"),
    ("B", "Both")
)

class Player(models.Model):
    ...
    strong_foot = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STRING_FOOT)
    ...
```

I can chose to display the value instead of the key of the choices like this in my serializers:

```
class JoueurSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    strong_foot = serializers.CharField(source="get_strong_foot_display")
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = "__all__"
```

The issue I have is that I have more than 30 attributs in my models. Is there a way to ask DRF to show automatically  the value instead of the key of the choice field in the list view ? Or do I need to do what I did in the serializers for all of my attributs ?

Answer (score 0):

works with any field with choices, with no need to specify in the serializer a custom method for each:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class ChoicesSerializerField(serializers.SerializerMethodField):
    """
    A read-only field that return the representation of a model field with choices.
    """

    def to_representation(self, value):
        # sample: 'get_XXXX_display'
        method_name = 'get_{field_name}_display'.format(field_name=self.field_name)
        # retrieve instance method
        method = getattr(value, method_name)
        # finally use instance method to return result of get_XXXX_display()
        return method()
```